# JSON to FormData – JSON Object with Array having Files, Not Binding to Parameter in Controller Action

Tags: angular, typescript, controller, form-data, .net-5

I am using TypeScript from an Angular app, I am building FormData from JSON object which has array, and each array element has a file and other string properties. When posting FormData to controller, it is not bound to the action parameter.
I have tried few solutions from [here](https://gist.github.com/ghinda/8442a57f22099bdb2e34) also tried [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata) library.

**C# Models**

```
    public class FilesRequest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public IList<AddedFile> AddedFiles { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddedFile
    {
        public string SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
        public string SomeProperty2 { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller action:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(bool))]
        public async Task<bool> Process( [FromForm] FilesRequest filesRequest)
        {
            // Process
            return true;
        }
```

**TypeScript:**

```
data:any = {
    id:'xxxxxxx',
    addedFiles:[]
  }

onFileSelect(event:any){
    const file = event.target.files[0]; 
    this.data.addedFiles.push(
      {
        'someProperty1 ':'value1',
        'someProperty2 ':'value2',
        'file':file
      }
    );
  }

  postRequest(){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', this.data.id);
    // How to appent data.addedFiles to formData?
    //Post data
  }
```

**It works fine in the following form i.e. Id and files are bound on receiving the request in the controller action:**

```
    public class FilesRequest
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public IList<IFormFile> files { get; set; }
    }

    simpleData:any = {
       id:'xxxxxxx',
       files:[]
    } 

  onFileSelect(event:any){
    const file = event.target.files[0]; 
    this.simpleData.addedFiles.push(file);
  }

   postRequest(){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', this.simpleData.id);    
    this.simpleData.files.forEach((file: any) => {
      formData.append('files', file);
    });
    
    //Post data
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Appeared to be problem with the formatting of the key names in the key-value pairs in the FormData object. This method worked for me

   ```
     postRequest(){
   const formData = new FormData();   
   formData.append('id', this.data.id);       
   for(let index=0; index<this.data.addedFiles.length; index++)
   {
     formData.append(`addedFiles[${index}].someProperty1`, this.data.addedFiles[index].someProperty1);
     formData.append(`addedFiles[${index}].someProperty2`, this.data.addedFiles[index].someProperty2);
     formData.append(`addedFiles[${index}].file`, this.data.addedFiles[index].file);
   }  

   // code to post...
   ```

   }
2. The library also worked fine when using *indices:true* in the options

   postRequest(){
   const formData = serialize(
   this.data,
   {
   indices:true
   }
   );

   ```
   // code to post the data
   ```

   }

Comment: In previously solution I said that the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata did not work but reason was I did not set the option indices to true